# GParted failing to resize partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to resize a partition on the flash drive I'm running Ubuntu on as per the instructions in this guide: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/#more-4047. My goal is to have a larger casper-rw partition than 4GB.

However, when I try to do the first resize operation mentioned in the guide, GParted is giving me the following error:

```
GParted 0.11.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid

Libparted 2.3
Shrink /dev/sde1 from 28.91 GiB to 1.09 GiB  00:00:04    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sde1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sde1
start: 2,048
end: 60,631,039
size: 60,628,992 (28.91 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sde1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

dosfsck -a -w -v /dev/sde1

dosfsck 3.0.12 (29 Oct 2011)
dosfsck 3.0.12, 29 Oct 2011, FAT32, LFN
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
Differences: (offset:original/backup)
1:58/5a, 3:53/4d, 4:59/53, 5:53/57, 6:4c/49, 7:49/4e, 8:4e/34, 9:55/2e
, 10:58/31, 90:fa/00, 91:fc/00, 92:31/00, 93:c9/00, 94:8e/00, 95:d1/00
, 96:bc/00, 97:76/00, 98:7b/00, 99:52/00, 100:06/00, 101:57/00, 102:1e/00
, 103:56/00, 104:8e/00, 105:c1/00, 106:b1/00, 107:26/00, 108:bf/00
, 109:78/00, 110:7b/00, 111:f3/00, 112:a5/00, 113:8e/00, 114:d9/00
, 115:bb/00, 116:78/00, 118:0f/00, 119:b4/00, 120:37/00, 121:0f/00
, 122:a0/00, 123:56/00, 124:20/00, 125:d2/00, 126:78/00, 127:1b/00
, 128:31/00, 129:c0/00, 130:b1/00, 131:06/00, 132:89/00, 133:3f/00
, 134:89/00, 135:47/00, 136:02/00, 137:f3/00, 138:64/00, 139:a5/00
, 140:8a/00, 141:0e/00, 142:18/00, 143:7c/00, 144:88/00, 145:4d/00
, 146:f8/00, 147:50/00, 148:50/00, 149:50/00, 150:50/00, 151:cd/00
, 152:13/00, 153:eb/00, 154:62/00, 155:8b/00, 156:55/00, 157:aa/00
, 158:8b/00, 159:75/00, 160:a8/00, 161:c1/00, 162:ee/00, 163:04/00
, 164:01/00, 165:f2/00, 166:83/00, 167:fa/00, 168:4f/00, 169:76/00
, 170:31/00, 171:81/00, 172:fa/00, 173:b2/00, 174:07/00, 175:73/00
, 176:2b/00, 177:f6/00, 178:45/00, 179:b4/00, 180:7f/00, 181:75/00
, 182:25/00, 183:38/00, 184:4d/00, 185:b8/00, 186:74/00, 187:20/00
, 188:66/00, 189:3d/00, 190:21/00, 191:47/00, 192:50/00, 193:54/00
, 194:75/00, 195:10/00, 196:80/00, 197:7d/00, 198:b8/00, 199:ed/00
, 200:75/00, 201:0a/00, 202:66/00, 203:ff/00, 204:75/00, 205:ec/00
, 206:66/00, 207:ff/00, 208:75/00, 209:e8/00, 210:eb/00, 211:0f/00
, 212:51/00, 213:51/00, 214:66/00, 215:ff/00, 216:75/00, 217:bc/00
, 218:eb/00, 219:07/00, 220:51/00, 221:51/00, 222:66/00, 223:ff/00
, 224:36/00, 225:1c/00, 226:7c/00, 227:b4/00, 228:08/00, 229:e8/00
, 230:e9/00, 232:72/00, 233:13/00, 234:20/00, 235:e4/00, 236:75/00
, 237:0f/00, 238:c1/00, 239:ea/00, 240:08/00, 241:42/00, 242:89/00
, 243:16/00, 244:1a/00, 245:7c/00, 246:83/00, 247:e1/00, 248:3f/00
, 249:89/00, 250:0e/00, 251:18/00, 252:7c/00, 253:fb/00, 254:bb/00
, 255:aa/00, 256:55/00, 257:b4/00, 258:41/00, 259:e8/00, 260:cb/00
, 262:72/00, 263:10/00, 264:81/00, 265:fb/00, 266:55/00, 267:aa/00
, 268:75/00, 269:0a/00, 270:f6/00, 271:c1/00, 272:01/00, 273:74/00
, 274:05/00, 275:c6/00, 276:06/00, 277:46/00, 278:7d/00, 280:66/00
, 281:b8/00, 282:16/00, 283:74/00, 286:66/00, 287:ba/00, 292:bb/00
, 294:80/00, 295:e8/00, 296:0e/00, 298:66/00, 299:81/00, 300:3e/00
, 301:1c/00, 302:80/00, 303:a1/00, 304:f3/00, 305:42/00, 306:6f/00
, 307:75/00, 308:74/00, 309:e9/00, 310:f8/00, 311:02/00, 312:66/00
, 313:03/00, 314:06/00, 315:60/00, 316:7b/00, 317:66/00, 318:13/00
, 319:16/00, 320:64/00, 321:7b/00, 322:b9/00, 323:10/00, 325:eb/00
, 326:2b/00, 327:66/00, 328:52/00, 329:66/00, 330:50/00, 331:06/00
, 332:53/00, 333:6a/00, 334:01/00, 335:6a/00, 336:10/00, 337:89/00
, 338:e6/00, 339:66/00, 340:60/00, 341:b4/00, 342:42/00, 343:e8/00
, 344:77/00, 346:66/00, 347:61/00, 348:8d/00, 349:64/00, 350:10/00
, 351:72/00, 352:01/00, 353:c3/00, 354:66/00, 355:60/00, 356:31/00
, 357:c0/00, 358:e8/00, 359:68/00, 361:66/00, 362:61/00, 363:e2/00
, 364:da/00, 365:c6/00, 366:06/00, 367:46/00, 368:7d/00, 369:2b/00
, 370:66/00, 371:60/00, 372:66/00, 373:0f/00, 374:b7/00, 375:36/00
, 376:18/00, 377:7c/00, 378:66/00, 379:0f/00, 380:b7/00, 381:3e/00
, 382:1a/00, 383:7c/00, 384:66/00, 385:f7/00, 386:f6/00, 387:31/00
, 388:c9/00, 389:87/00, 390:ca/00, 391:66/00, 392:f7/00, 393:f7/00
, 394:66/00, 395:3d/00, 396:ff/00, 397:03/00, 400:77/00, 401:17/00
, 402:c0/00, 403:e4/00, 404:06/00, 405:41/00, 406:08/00, 407:e1/00
, 408:88/00, 409:c5/00, 410:88/00, 411:d6/00, 412:b8/00, 413:01/00
, 414:02/00, 415:e8/00, 416:2f/00, 418:66/00, 419:61/00, 420:72/00
, 421:01/00, 422:c3/00, 423:e2/00, 424:c9/00, 425:31/00, 426:f6/00
, 427:8e/00, 428:d6/00, 429:bc/00, 430:68/00, 431:7b/00, 432:8e/00
, 433:de/00, 434:66/00, 435:8f/00, 436:06/00, 437:78/00, 439:be/00
, 440:da/00, 441:7d/00, 442:ac/00, 443:20/00, 444:c0/00, 445:74/00
, 446:09/00, 447:b4/00, 448:0e/00, 449:bb/00, 450:07/00, 452:cd/00
, 453:10/00, 454:eb/00, 455:f2/00, 456:31/00, 457:c0/00, 458:cd/00
, 459:16/00, 460:cd/00, 461:19/00, 462:f4/00, 463:eb/00, 464:fd/00
, 465:8a/00, 466:16/00, 467:74/00, 468:7b/00, 469:06/00, 470:cd/00
, 471:13/00, 472:07/00, 473:c3/00, 474:42/00, 475:6f/00, 476:6f/00
, 477:74/00, 478:20/00, 479:65/00, 480:72/00, 481:72/00, 482:6f/00
, 483:72/00, 484:0d/00, 485:0a/00, 504:fe/00, 505:02/00, 506:b2/00
, 507:3e/00, 508:18/00, 509:37/00
Not automatically fixing this.
Boot sector contents:
System ID "SYSLINUX"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
512 bytes per logical sector
16384 bytes per cluster
32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
2 FATs, 32 bit entries
7575040 bytes per FAT (= 14795 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 15166464 (sector 29622)
1893730 data clusters (31026872320 bytes)
63 sectors/track, 255 heads
2048 hidden sectors
60628992 sectors total
Reclaiming unconnected clusters.
Checking free cluster summary.
/dev/sde1: 3059 files, 70669/1893730 clusters
shrink file system  00:00:04    ( ERROR )

using libparted
libparted messages    ( INFO )

fat_table_alloc_cluster: no free clusters
```

I don't know anything about GParted. However, I don't think the USB is the problem as I just bought it, and chkdisk on Windows didn't reveal any problems. Any ideas how to fix this error? Here is output of df:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            8.0G   36M  7.9G   1% /
udev            7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  980K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdc1       3.7G  759M  2.9G  21% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      722M  722M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs           8.0G  8.0K  8.0G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            8.0G   76K  8.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sde1        29G  1.1G   28G   4% /media/UUI
```

Comment: Why would you be trying to shrink 28.91 GiB to 1.09 GiB?

Comment: I'm following the guide mentioned in my post. I want to shrink it down to 1.09 GiB, then use the freed space for a casper-rw partition.

Comment: How big is the pendrive?

Comment: It's 32 GB, just bought it yesterday

Comment: So how are you planning on making this bootable if you resize the only existing partition down to 1GiB?

Comment: It's already bootable. The remaining 1 GiB is for Ubuntu

Comment: A bootable Ubuntu can't exist in 1GiB. Or am I missing what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm following this guide: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/#more-4047. I've already run their tool to create a bootable USB, I think that step is what is using the 1 GiB. What I want to do now is create a casper-rw partition so I can have persistent storage when I run Ubuntu off the USB.

Comment: Those instructions just don't look right. You're trying to reduce a 29G partition down to 1.09G and there's already 1.1G used in that partition. If you resize to 2G it might work.

Comment: Those instructions are old and the screenshots even older.  It works if you don't ask for impossible situations like shrinking a partition to a size less than the contents already there. And you probably don't need persistence anyway. If you intend to have a portable Ubuntu you would be better doing a normal installation (from another flash drive or DVD) in the 32GB flash drive, plenty of space there.